# create PDF file from android

Tags: android, pdf

Can we create PDF file from android application, do any libraries available to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bruno Lowagie, the primary author of iText is currently working on an Android port.  Several others have done it piecemeal, hacking away large sections of code they didn't need.  Bruno is going Hole Hog, converting just about everything.

No idea when he'll be done (or even "if" for that matter).  Pre-alpha.  Could be vaporware.  I don't even know that it compiles at the moment.

Note also that iText is available under the AGPL and as a commercial license.  If your code is GPL, you're fine.  If you want to keep your source closed, you'll need a commercial license.